# Could not find a matching alpn-boot JAR for Java version: 12.0.2

Tags: jetty, grpc, alpn, akka-grpc

Running `sbt run` on a Scala, akka-grpc project, [based on their basic tutorial](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-grpc/current/server/walkthrough.html#running-the-server) I get:

```
[error] [jetty-alpn-agent] Could not find a matching alpn-boot JAR for Java version: 12.0.2
```

Is alpn-boot not compatible with Java 12 yet? What is this trying to say? Does it work with Java 11? Can I make it work with 12 making it believe it's Java 11?

[[full source code](https://github.com/kovacshuni/grpc-try)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no alpn-boot requirement for Java 9+

That's because ALPN is built into Java starting in Java 9.

See: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-jdk9

Comment: You're right, the answer was to remove all `enablePlugins(JavaAgent)` and `javaAgents += ` dependency definitions from `build.sbt`, Java 12 does not need any manual launch setting. Thanks.